# Как программно изменить текст вкладки в tabhost

Tags: android

Всем привет! Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно изменить программно текст вкладки в tabhost?Например на первой вкладке расположить кнопку, и в обработчике события написать код который изменяет заголовок второй вкладки. Я пробовал применять у вкладки метод setIndicator, но что-то у меня не получается.

Вот код:

```
 package com.project.qwer;

 import android.os.Bundle;  
 import android.app.Activity;  
 import android.view.Menu;  
 import android.view.View;  
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;  
 import android.view.ViewGroup;  
 import android.widget.LinearLayout;  
 import android.widget.RelativeLayout;  
 import android.widget.TabHost;  
 import android.widget.TabWidget;  
 import android.widget.TextView;  
 import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{  
    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec1;  
    TabHost myTab;

    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
        myTab = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);  
        myTab.setup();  
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = myTab.newTabSpec("tab1");

        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tab1);  
        tabSpec.setIndicator("tab1");    
        myTab.addTab(tabSpec);

        tabSpec1 = myTab.newTabSpec("tab2");  
        tabSpec1.setContent(R.id.tab2);  
        tabSpec1.setIndicator("tab2");  
        myTab.addTab(tabSpec1);

        myTab.setCurrentTab(0);  
        TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ttt);  
        txt.setOnClickListener(this);  
    }

    @Override  
    public void onClick(View arg0) {  
        // Когда нажимаешь на кнопку, то ничего не происходит  
        tabSpec1.setIndicator("asdfasdf");  
    }

}
```

Comment: Вы в вопросе неоднократно упоминаете нажатие на кнопку, однако, по коду, я вижу лишь обработчик нажатия на `TextView`.

Answer (score 2):

> Скажите пожалуйста как можно изменить программно текст вкладки в tabhost?

[`setIndicator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html#setIndicator(java.lang.CharSequence)).

> Я пробовал применять у вкладки метод setIndicator, но что-то у меня не получается.

Что "что-то" не получается? Не компилируется код, возникает runtime exception, не меняется заголовок таба?

И не ленитесь показывать код, не ждите, когда вас явно об этом попросят. *Смешная шутка про телепатов в отпуске.*

Answer (score 0):

После

```
tabSpec1.setIndicator("asdfasdf");
```

используйте

```
myTab.addTab(tabSpec1);
```